# Can't run Bazel nodejs_image with Puppeteer (Error: libgobject-2.0.so.0)

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

I am using Bazel to build Docker containers:

```
ts_config(
    name = "tsconfig",
    src = "tsconfig.lib.json",
)

ts_project(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = ["index.ts"],
    declaration = True,
    tsconfig = "tsconfig",
    deps = [
        "@npm//@types/node",
        "@npm//puppeteer",
    ],
)

nodejs_binary(
    name = "server",
    data = [
        "lib",
    ],
    entry_point = "index.ts",
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "image",
    binary = "server",
)
```

Running the `nodejs_binary` works fine.

But running the `nodejs_image` "image" throws an error:

```
(node:44) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/app/server.runfiles/node_puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

---

Hence I've tried to add a custom `base` ([this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker) one) image like this:

```
nodejs_image(
    name = "base_image",
    base = "@nodejs_puppeteer//image",
    binary = "server",
)
```

and in `WORKSPACE`:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_pull")

container_pull(
    name = "nodejs_puppeteer",
    digest = "sha256:22ec485fa257ec892efc2a8b69ef9a3a2a81a0f6622969ffe2d416d2a076214b",
    registry = "docker.io",
    repository = "drakery/node-puppeteer:latest",
)
```

However running the updated `nodejs_image` "base_image", throws this error:

```
[link_node_modules.js] An error has been reported: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/app/server.runfiles/npm/node_modules' -> 'node_modules'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'symlink',
  path: '/app/server.runfiles/npm/node_modules',
  dest: 'node_modules'
} Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/app/server.runfiles/npm/node_modules' -> 'node_modules'
```

---

How can I add the missing dependencies into the `nodejs_image`?

A minimal reproduction of the issue can be found here: https://github.com/flolu/bazel-node-puppeteer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@Rohan Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288425/rohan-singh) and [@Noam Yizraeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459640/noam-yizraeli), I've tried to change the custom base image to my development environment.
Hence I've created a Docker image with Ubuntu as is it's base and Node.js as well as Chrome installed:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install Node.js
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

# Install Chrome
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
  && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
  --no-install-recommends \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I pulled it in Bazel like this:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_pull")

container_pull(
    name = "ubuntu",
    digest = "sha256:a1ceb3aac586b6377821ffe6aede35c3646649ee5ac38c3566799cd04745257f",
    registry = "docker.io",
    repository = "drakery/node-puppeteer",
)
```

And used it like this:

```
nodejs_image(
    name = "custom_ubuntu",
    base = "@ubuntu//image",
    binary = "server",
)
```

Here is the final working repository: https://github.com/flolu/bazel-node-puppeteer/tree/050376d36bccb67a93933882a459f0af3051eabd

Comment: If you want to take it a step further, there are experimental `dockerfile_build` rules in `rules_docker`. You can use this to build the base image as part of a Bazel run. However, it requires a working Docker installation and is not hermetic.

Comment: @RohanSingh would love to do that! But I couldn't make it work: running `yarn bazelisk run //:bazel_ubuntu` from this branch: https://github.com/flolu/bazel-node-puppeteer/tree/docker-bazel doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That's still using `container_image` for the base image. I mean adding a `dockerfile_image` to your `WORKSPACE` to build your `Dockerfile` base image. Example: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/8c3a8110a0c519929a7e79c39ac345a0f8c74d04/testing/examples/WORKSPACE#L64

Answer (score 2):

This is a long-standing issue with building native dependencies with `rules_nodejs`.

The native dependency is built and linked on your host machine. The built version is copied into a container image by `nodejs_image`, but the locations of shared libraries like `libgobject-2.0.so.0` is often different in the image than on your development machine.

There is no general solution to this, but here are some possible workarounds:

1. **Run `npm rebuild` in the entrypoint to your image.** This should rebuild native modules and relink them based on the shared library locations in the running container. The downside is that it will increase your container startup time, and it won't necessarily work in all cases. Environment-specific stuff can still leak in from the host platform.
2. **Don't copy in `node_modules` from the host at all.** Instead, run `npm install` or `yarn` on container startup. This could be necessary if just running `npm rebuild` at container startup doesn't do what you need. However, it's going to increase startup time even further.
3. **Strictly control your development environment so that it matches the base image that you use for `nodejs_image`.** For example, require that all development work happens on Ubuntu 20.04, and use that same distribution as the base image for all your `nodejs_image` targets. Or go a step further and containerize your development environment using the same base image, and do your development in that container.

That last option is what I actually do in practice. We have developer virtual machines that run the exact same OS that we use as the base for all of our built images, so things "just work".

Comment: I appreciate your comprehensive answer, Rohan. Workaround 1 and 2 are not an option since Bazel (rules_nodejs) handles those things under the hood. Option 3 sounds good. I've tried to use the same base image as my dev system (Ubuntu 20.04). But I get this error: `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`. Any ideas? You can try it yourself: https://github.com/flolu/bazel-node-puppeteer#ubuntu-as-base-throws-error

Comment: @FlorianLudewig I think he meant you use an ubuntu-based nodejs image, maybe use [this](https://gist.github.com/RinatMullayanov/89687a102e696b1d4cab) or similar dockerfile as base instead

Comment: You can use the nodejs_image target as a layer to build a container_image. That's how you can customize the entry point to add things like `npm rebuild`.

Comment: To troubleshoot other issues like the exec format issue, use the `docker` CLI to inspect the built image and see what it's actually trying to run. My guess is that the Ubuntu-based image is trying to `exec` a JS script directly.